# How to use GDB plugin in Geany?

Tags: debugging, gdb, geany

I have installed GDB plugin in Geany, which shows a tab as Debug. I am OK to use GDB in terminal, but cannot figure our a way using that Debug tab.

Opening the tab, I can see several windows. I loaded an binary file into Target tab, then run it. Geany crashed immediately. In addition, most of buttons, such as step in, are in gray. Could not fine an online doc.

Could anyone instruct me?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/31635524/2915834 could give a start

Answer (score 0):

If you installed geany-plugins, you can activate debug :
menu->tools->plugin manager checkbox the debugger

and you can use it with your file name path witch means that
if your file name is gg
./gg   is your path. not gg.c